# SVG Two path and one ball animation

Tags: css, animation, svg

Hey it's my first time with svg and animations but i don't get it.. I've got code like that:

```css
.ball {
  offset-path: path('M417.000,237.000 L54.000,237.000 C26.386,237.000 4.000,214.614 4.000,187.000 L4.000,4.000 M425.500,237.000 L718.500,237.000 C746.114,237.000 768.500,259.386 768.500,287.000 L768.500,470.000');
  offset-distance: 0%;

  animation: red-ball 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes red-ball {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="775px" height="474px">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd"  stroke="rgb(79, 191, 159)" stroke-width="4px" stroke-dasharray="2, 8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none"
  d="M417.000,237.000 L54.000,237.000 C26.386,237.000 4.000,214.614 4.000,187.000 L4.000,4.000 "/>
  <path fill-rule="evenodd"  stroke="rgb(79, 191, 159)" stroke-width="4px" stroke-dasharray="2, 8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none"
  d="M425.500,237.000 L718.500,237.000 C746.114,237.000 768.500,259.386 768.500,287.000 L768.500,470.000 "/>
  <path class="ball" fill-rule="evenodd"  stroke="rgb(79, 191, 159)" stroke-width="1px" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" fill="rgb(79, 191, 159)"
                                  d="M4.500,0.500 C6.709,0.500 8.500,2.291 8.500,4.500 C8.500,6.709 6.709,8.500 4.500,8.500 C2.291,8.500 0.500,6.709 0.500,4.500 C0.500,2.291 2.291,0.500 4.500,0.500 Z"/>
</svg>
```

What i want to do:

1. I cannot create combination of this two first path to one, to get linear slim ball animation (when i convert two shape to one i've got something like that:

```html
<svg 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 width="775px" height="473px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  stroke="rgb(79, 191, 159)" stroke-width="4px" stroke-dasharray="2, 8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel" fill="none"
 d="M425.500,236.000 L718.500,236.000 C746.114,236.000 768.500,258.386 768.500,286.000 L768.500,469.000 L425.500,236.000 ZM4.000,186.000 L4.000,3.000 L417.000,236.000 L54.000,236.000 C26.386,236.000 4.000,213.614 4.000,186.000 Z"/>
</svg>
```

2. Line in illustrator got circles, but in generate SVG we've got lines.. (preview image show what i want to look like): [image]
3. Some idea to animate ball from circle to circle, not linear but one by one... Is it possible without javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I've rewritten your path by reversing the second one, and joining them in one path. I'm using the same path for the `offset-path` in CSS.
2. for the second part of your question I'm using `stroke-dasharray:.1, 8;`. Please note that the strokes are very small: 0.1 units. Also I'm using `stroke-linecap:round;` This will add round "caps" to the very small strokes, making them look like circles.
3. In order to reduce verbosity and make the code more readable I've moved the presentational attributes for the paths is CSS.

I hope this is what you wanted.

```css
path{stroke:rgb(79, 191, 159);
  stroke-linecap:round; 
  fill:none;
  stroke-width:4px;
  stroke-dasharray:.1, 8;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
}

.ball {
  stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;fill:rgb(79, 191, 159);
  offset-path: path("M768.500,470.000 L768.500,287.000C768.500,259.386 746.114,237.000 718.500,237.000L425.500,237.000L54.000,237.000 C26.386,237.000 4.000,214.614 4.000,187.000 L4.000,4.000");
  offset-distance: 0%;

  animation: red-ball 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes red-ball {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }
  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 775 474">
  <!---<path  
  d="M417.000,237.000 L54.000,237.000 C26.386,237.000 4.000,214.614 4.000,187.000 L4.000,4.000 "/>
  <path 
  d="M425.500,237.000 L718.500,237.000 C746.114,237.000 768.500,259.386 768.500,287.000 L768.500,470.000 "/>-->
  
  <path 
  d="M768.500,470.000 L768.500,287.000C768.500,259.386 746.114,237.000 718.500,237.000L425.500,237.000L54.000,237.000 C26.386,237.000 4.000,214.614 4.000,187.000 L4.000,4.000"/>
  
  <path class="ball" d="M4.500,0.500 C6.709,0.500 8.500,2.291 8.500,4.500 C8.500,6.709 6.709,8.500 4.500,8.500 C2.291,8.500 0.500,6.709 0.500,4.500 C0.500,2.291 2.291,0.500 4.500,0.500 Z"/>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP commented:

> Can you explain a little bit more about rewriten

In order to reverse a path you need to reverse everything. In this example:

```
 <path 
   d="M425.500,237.000 
      L718.500,237.000 
      C746.114,237.000 768.500,259.386 768.500,287.000
      L768.500,470.000" />
```

The reversed path begins where the previous path ends:

```
d="M768.500,470.000...
```

Next I draw a line to the point where the Bézier curve ends:

```
d=".....
   L768.500,287.000
```

Now I reverse the Bézier curve: the second control point becomes the first and the first control point is now the second. The Bézier curve ends where the previous line ended:

```
d=".....
C768.500,259.386 746.114,237.000 718.500,237.000
```

Finally I draw a line that ends where the previous curve began:

```
d="...
   L425.500,237.000"
```

Putting it all together:, this is the reversed path:

```
 <path 
   d="M768.500,470.000
      L768.500,287.000
      C768.500,259.386 746.114,237.000 718.500,237.000
      L425.500,237.000" />
```

Comment: WOW You're rock! I try to rewrite path but... Can you explain a little bit more about rewriten?

Comment: And just one more question. Is possible to animate this .ball to grow on every single circle in first path? Grow and back to normal. With just pure css? Or i need use javascript for it?

Comment: I've edited my answer where I explain how to reverse a path. Please take a look. As for your second comment, this is a different question. So please ask it as a different question. I'll be glad to help.